# Center an <a> tag inside of an <img> tag with CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I am in the case as follows:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div>
            <img src="xxx.png">
            <a>bla_bla1<a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <img src="yyy.png">
            <a>bla_bla2<a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And I would like to align the text ( tag) on center of the image.

Thank you.

EDIT: Some extra details:

I have 2 images, one small and one big (like buttons). The smal image is in the div's left position and the big on the div's right position.

My goal is to align the two texts in the center of the image, one in the center of the small image, the other in the center of the big image.

Comment: You have to reverse the tag order, put the `<img>` inside the `<a>`

Comment: @Andy Why would an image tag inside an anchor tag be invalid? `<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>ttt</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#"><img src="tt.png" alt="tt"></a>
</body>
</html>` gives valid html according to [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: @Andy - an `img` inside an `a` causing invalid html? I'm pretty sure that would make every site since 1994

Comment: Also, align text to center? Horizontally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the div and `absolute` to a tag

```
 a{
    position:absolute; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:100%;
    top:40%; left:0; 
    color:red; 
    font-size:25px;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WKBu5/6/)**

---

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/WKBu5/8/)**

Comment: With your positioning it only works on the sample text. It will not fit to shorter or longer texts.

Comment: @Amberlamps Updated the answer. Now it works for longer text too

Comment: I can approve this answer now :)

Comment: @Sowmya, thanks a lot, but I would like to have two images one smaller and one bigger, one near the other (smaller on the left and bigger on the right) and the texts should be inside of each image aligned on center

Comment: @Sowmya, thank you, but it seems that the link is pointing to the same address.

Comment: @Sowmya, I am facing a problem: In my example, the two divs are in the same td, is it possible to align the text in the center of the image if the two images are in the same dvi? Thank you.

Comment: If you check in the  inspect element, there is 'a' tag creating dynamically around the second div's img tag. that is why it is not aligning inside the same td. I am trying to find why there is an extra a tag generating

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal align:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVqfM/

```
div{float:left; width:auto;}
a{display:inline-block; width:100%; text-align:center;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the text in front of image?

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/AjFur/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method too *(works for modern browsers **)*

http://jsfiddle.net/zW47f/

http://jsfiddle.net/zW47f/1/ <-- found `margin-top:-25%` affected by text width, so changed to `-1em`

**css:**

```
/* By adding position relative, overflow hidden and float left you definitely 
   force the browser to calc it's percentage positioning based on the div 
   not the td */
td div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: both; /* <-- Remove if you want your divs to display inline */
}

/* By wrapping with a span you can shift elements twice, once to the middle */
td div span {
    display: block;
    left: 50%; top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

/* ... and once back with an offset based on the dimensions of the text */
td div span a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%; /* <-- will work for any width of text < the div's width */
    margin-top: -1em; /* <-- this will only work for single lines of text */
}
```

**markup:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <img src="xxx.png" />
        <span><a>bla_bla1</a></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="yyy.png" />
        <span><a>bla_bla2</a></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*** Means I haven't tested in Internet Explorer*

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div align="center" style="float:left;  position:absolute;">
            <img src="xxx.png">
            <a>bla_bla1<a>
         </div>
         <div align="center" style="float:right;  position:absolute; ">
            <img src="yyy.png">
            <a>bla_bla2<a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```